# How to order records by certain value in Doctrine?

Tags: php, zend-framework, doctrine-orm, sql-order-by, dql

I am using the following query to retrieve all keyword records with the ones belonging to the group record with id=2 appearing first. This seems to work fine.

```
 SELECT k.*, g.groupid, kg.keywordid
  FROM keywords k
  JOIN keywords_groups kg ON k.keywordid=kg.keywordid
  JOIN groups g ON kg.groupid=g.groupid
 ORDER BY kg.groupid = 2 DESC;
```

However I am trying to translate this into DQL but keep getting the following error:

```
[Syntax Error] line 0, col 198: Error: Expected end of string, got '='
```

It seems the problematic line in my DQL is:

```
->orderBy($keywordQB->expr()->eq('g.groupid', ':keyword_group_id'), 'ASC')
```

It seems to me Doctrine doesn't support this and I can't think of an alternative way doing this in DQL.

Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

Doctrine is support this.   try this one

```
$query = Doctrine_Query::create()
                ->select('k.*, g.groupid, kg.keywordid')
                ->from('keywords k')
                ->innerJoin('keywordsGroups kg ON k.keywordid=kg.keywordid')
                ->innerJoin('Groups g ON kg.groupid=g.groupid')
                ->orderBy('kg.groupid = 2 DESC');
        $result = $query->execute(array(), Doctrine::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
        return $result;
```

Comment: That snippet looks like DQL for Doctrine 1. I'm using Doctrine 2.

Comment: Try   ->orderBy('kg.groupid = 2', 'DESC'));